# Excel, autofill column of an Excel table based on same column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to autocomplete a column:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| Name  |  Currently Employed?  |
+-------+-----------------------+
| John  |                       |
| Tom   |                       |
| John  |                       |
| John. | Yes                   |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

If I update line 4, currently employed column, to yes. I want to find all other instances and update with the same value:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| Name  |  Currently Employed?  |
+-------+-----------------------+
| John  | -> Yes                |
| Tom   |                       |
| John  | -> Yes                |
| John. | Yes                   |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Any changes should be reflected across all instances of a name, regardless of order. For example, if:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| Name  |  Currently Employed?  |
+-------+-----------------------+
| John  | -> No                 |
| Tom   |                       |
| John  | Yes                   |
| John. | Yes                   |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Then:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| Name  |  Currently Employed?  |
+-------+-----------------------+
| John  | Yes                   |
| Tom   |                       |
| John  | -> No                 |
| John. | -> No                 |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, using VBA and the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Any idea of how I would implement? Unfortunately, I'm still a novice at VBA. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!